# Best practices for remote GUI access to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, remote-access, graphical-user-interface

I would like to get an overview of available solutions for having a *remote* GUI access to ubuntu server:
-do you recommend installing a basic GUI then administrating over VNC?
-is X11 forwarding a good option?
...

I know there are similar questions already but they all focus on 1 aspect of the problem whereas I think it would be good to get an overview.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of FreeNX for this as it performs well even over low bandwidth situations: [FreeNX on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX).  That, combined with [Blackbox](http://blackboxwm.sourceforge.net/) makes a very low overhead GUI solution for managing a server.

Comment: That sound's good. Could you explain a bit more how you "combine" FreeNX and Blackbox?

Comment: They have nothing to do with each other.  FreeNX is how you connect to the server, but without a window manager, you won't be able to move windows around.  Blackbox provides that, but it's definitely not the only option available.  It's just very lightweight & easily customizable & I think provides a good GUI for a server.

Answer (score 2):

vnc direct is not such a great idea but will work - requires a desktop environment installed on the server (takes up extra resources)

vnc over an ssh tunnel would be a secure way of doing it - same issues as direct vnc though

one way to not have to start up an x-server display locally on your system (and use up lots of vital resources) is to use something like freenx this will give you a remote desktop similar to MS Terminal Server, however if you need something of the shared screen environment that VNC will give you, this wont work

Comment: VNC is much more ubiquitous, and VNC over SSH is the easy way to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the quality of the connectivity you have:

good connectivity: you could go and use VNC

bad connectivity: use X11 for opening the window(s) you need.

Comment: My experience is the other way around:  Good connectivity = X11, Bad connectivity = VNC.

Comment: It really depends of the application you are trying to execute. In both case you should use -C on your ssh command to compress the stream.